# How to identify features that reduce the model's performance?

Tags: modeling, feature-selection

I see here many questions about identifying the most important features for the model but how to do the opposite, i.e. identify features that actually reduce the accuracy? Is the only way to actually randomly take the subset of features and compare the results? Or is there some "smart way" to do it?

Namely, I've tried to perform a feature selection procedure (removed features with low feature importance as given by the eg. random forest & remove collinear features), and the performance was the same as with all the features. Which wouldn't be so bad unless when I selected features by myself (made an "educated guess") I didn't get better performance than after writing the whole feature selection procedure.

(Also, I have a lot of collinear features as the features as group of min/max/mean/std values for some observed quantity.)